# Required parameters based on other parameters

Tags: c#, parameters

I am trying to call a method that requires some parameters based on previous parameters chosen.

This is probably better explained with an example:

```
public static void MyMethod (string p1, string p2, string p3 = "", string p4 = "")
{
}
```

What I want to achieve is requiring `p4` if `p3` is given.

If I were to call it like this:

```
MyMethod("Hello", "World", "P3", // p4 now required as p3 given a value)
```

I hope this makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of default values for parameters (which has its own problems), I would use overloading:

```
public static void MyMethod (string p1, string p2)
{
   MyMethod(p1, p2, "", "");
}

public static void MyMethod (string p1, string p2, string p3, string p4)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what @Aliostad suggested, which makes sense if this is the only requirement you have. If not, I think you'd better split the method into several methods with *different names*, so that people who call your methods don't get too confused.

Answer (score 1):

Probably above explanation is enough to resolve your issue. Code that you can write in overload method is mentioned below.

```
    public static void MyMethod (string p1, string p2)
{
   MyMthod(p1, p2, "", "");
}

public static void MyMethod (string p1, string p2, string p3, string p4)
{
   if(p3 has a value but p4 is missing the value)
    throw new Exception("p4 is required");

}
```

Comment: is it so hard for you to write this in c#? "p3 has a value but p4 is missing the value"

Comment: sorry about that, I thought it very simple and ignored the same.